# Using ObjectInputStream.available() as eqilivant to Scanner.hasNext()

Tags: java, networking, inputstream, objectinputstream

As it says in `ObjectInputStream.available()`'s javadoc:

> Returns the number of bytes that can be read without blocking.

we should be able to use following code just like `Scanner.hasNext()`

```
if (inputStream.available() > 0) {
    Object input = inputStream.readObject();
}
```

but when i use it even if there is some unread data in stream this condition doesn't get `true`.

Actually i'm using it in this way in a client-server application and it gets stuck at the `if`:

```
    while (continueListening) {
        Object responseObj;
        try {
            if (inputStream.available() == 0) { // this condition is always met
                continue;
            }
            responseObj = inputStream.readObject();
            .
            .
            .
```

Comment: "Without blocking" would seem to be the key phrase.

Comment: @LouisWasserman so when there is some data available to be read stream doesn't block the thread, does it?

Comment: Why vote down? I wrote the wrong code, i wasn't wrong to ask!

Comment: The term "blocking" _definitely_ includes "waiting for additional communication from the server."  `available()` will only return the number of bytes that have _already been received._

Comment: Using isConnected() like that is pointless. It doesn't magically become false when the peer disconnects. It becomes false when *you* disconnect. Maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`InputStream` JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29):

> Returns an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream without blocking by the next invocation of a method for this input stream.
>   [...]
>
> The available method for class InputStream always returns 0.

So it's generally not a good idea to rely on the result of `available()`, like you did. You are looping in case of `0`, doing a busy-wait for data. Rather you should use a dedicated thread and just call `readObject()` which will block until enough data is available or an exception is thrown, e.g. if the connection is closed while reading.

[`Scanner.hasNext()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28%29) might block as well, if the next token has not been read (completely).

Comment: I want to `while (continueListening)` be checked constantly because i may set `continueListening = false` when input stream is waiting for data but i know there ain't going to be anymore data and want to close connection

Comment: @MJafarMash: Just `close()` the `InputStream` from another thread if you want to terminate waiting for data. The `readObject()` method will be unblocked and throw an `IOException`.

Comment: Or set a read timeout and check your boolean every time it expires.